# Arraylist not working in JSP scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

When I am trying below code in Java 1.6/1.7 with Jboss 4.0 I am getting below exceptions. I don't have option here to use jstl.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /sample.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Syntax error on token "<", invalid AssignmentOperator

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /sample.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Syntax error on token "=", != expected

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /sample.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Syntax error on token "<", ( expected

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /sample.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Syntax error on token "(", invalid Expression           
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:397)
```

**My Jsp file is below :**

```
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>  

    <% ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();  
       list.add("Hello");  
    %>  

    <%= list.get(0) %>
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: and also, what version of Java is JBoss using?

Comment: More details on jsp file would help.

Comment: Find out what version of java jboss is running. Generics were introduced in Java 5, so if you are running java 4 it has no idea what `<>` means. Try using ArrayList without the `<String>` and see what happens.

Comment: What version of java  jboss using is 7,6 both i tried... Same result.

Comment: Pls tell how to check how to check java version in jboss...then i will correct myself..because in my system only java 7,6 jdk/jre installed...how jboss can point java 4..pls help

Comment: @Skabdus if you are still having this issue, try what I said and remove `<String>` from ArrayList. If that compiles correctly jboss is using Java 4.

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList<String> Orig_office_type = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
`

Answer (score 0):

`List <String> list = ArrayList<String>();`
Try this with List not ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Provide fully qualified class name:

```
java.util.ArrayList<String> Orig_office_type = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
```

This will resolve the issue.